# Drupal content with imag description and tabs

Tags: drupal, content-type

I have create a content type for drupal website as shown below:
[image: Content type]

**Is there any built in module similar to this or any tutorial links that would help me to start making this kind of content type** 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for starts, your going to need CCK to add custom fields to your content type (image, description, title, specifications, applications, design features)
http://drupal.org/project/cck

Your going to need to make some taxonomy to tag each of your nodes with
Once you create the taxonomy, create custom fields that are (Taxonomy Term References)

Drupal Quick Tabs will help create the "look & feel" for the bottom tab area
http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs

You most likely will need Views as well
http://drupal.org/project/views